# showing Database data in tables in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm very new to WordPress; I was wondering if someone would be able to let me know how I can add one of my database tables in a table format in one of my pages in WordPress; I did a research and I found this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hb3lfwq1bfM but I don't know whether "wpData Tables" is a plugin that I need to install or...? I don't have that option in my wordpress!

If you need more clarification please let me know.

If someone can show me the right direction, I appreciate it :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your page.php add this code within the loop at required area.

Replace values of `$my_page_id`, `$table_name` and add columns as per your requirement.

```
<?php
$my_page_id = 111; // page ID here
if( get_the_ID() === $my_page_id) { 

global $wpdb;
$table_name = 'your_table_name_here';
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT column_1, column_2, column_3 FROM ". $table_name); // add columns as you want
?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ( $myrows as $myrow ) {  ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $myrow->column_1; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $myrow->column_2; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $myrow->column_3; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Hi Omair, Sorry if I ask a silly question; but where is this page.php? Is it exactly the same name? Sorry I am pretty new to WP!Assume you create a new project where does page.php go? Thanks

Comment: page.php is at: `/wp-content/themes/{theme-name}/page.php` at your web server. Here is how you can find out where is page ID: http://goo.gl/QTdkPJ. I hope you know the database table name and column names that you want to retrieve `:)`

Comment: YEa I know :D But is it something like PHP or ... that we need to pass database configuration like host, password ,DBname? If so where am I supposed to pass these configs? You are very helpful man. Thanks :)

Comment: Is the database table not in Wordpress database? Is it remote and somewhere else?

Comment: I got it! It is cool :D My first experience with WP! Thanks for your patience:)